# Models similar to CAPM

Tags: finance

I'm using the capital asset pricing model (CAPM) to estimate the values of some assets.

I'm curious if there are other (simple if possible) models similar to it.
I want to apply as many models on my assets as possible.

Comment: Yes there are. http://aswathdamodaran.blogspot.pt/2011/04/alternatives-to-capm-part-1-relative.html

Comment: As written, this is too broad. You should update your question to explain the dimension on which you are looking for models to be similar. Linear return models with a single factor? Multiple linear models? Non-linear models using the market portfolio? Models where you borrow and lend at the same rate?